# SQL Where Not Exists Containing Multiple Arguments

Tags: sql, where-clause, exists

I am trying to write a query to retrieve data that only exists in one table, I also have other arguments that need to be addressed I have researched the Syntax but I am not understanding why my other Arguments are not being used. Sorry if this post seems rather inexperienced I have only been using SQL for a month.

```
/*List the patient id, primary diagnosis and attending physician id for current admissions (no discharge date) in ICU 
who haven't had an encounter with their attending physician.*/


PRINT 'GROUP 5 SELECT A';
PRINT '';

SELECT Admissions.PatientID, Admissions.PrimaryDiagnosis, Admissions.AttendingPhysicianID
FROM Admissions
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
   (SELECT *
    FROM Encounters
    WHERE (Admissions.PatientID = Encounters.PatientID)) And (Admissions.DischargeDate is NULL) And (Admissions.NursingUnitID = 'ICU');
```

Comment: I doubt whether the conditions `(Admissions.DischargeDate is NULL)` and `(Admissions.NursingUnitID = 'ICU')` should be inside the subselect, but I', not sure, since it's hard to figure out what the logic should be exactly.

Comment: How would I write my Syntax to put them outside of the subselect?

Comment: Remove the very last `)` and put it after `(Admissions.PatientID = Encounters.PatientID) `.

Comment: I edited my code and removed the Join as I realized I could just use PhysicianID from the Admissions table, I believe your solution resolved my problem but strangely now I am receiving zero results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your description, I am guessing that you need a match on both the patient and the physician.  Something like this:

```
SELECT a.PatientID, a.PrimaryDiagnosis, a.AttendingPhysicianID
FROM Admissions a
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM Encounters e
                  WHERE a.PatientID = e.PatientID AND
                        a.AttendingPhysicianID = e.PhysicianID
                 ) And
      a.DischargeDate is NULL And a.NursingUnitID = 'ICU';
```

Notice that the table aliases make the query easier to write and to read.

Comment: I really like the table aliases I will definitely look that up, Thank-you for your help!